Movie about demons that turn children into more of them
I watched this movie over a decade ago. I remember that the movie starts with a man's family getting attacked by demons.
His two children get dragged off underground and are never seen again. One night, the same town gets attacked by the demonic creatures again.
The movie revolves around the man and a group of other townspeople trying to survive the attack. Along the way, there is a scene of a sheriff looking for a man named O'Brien, only to see him getting mauled to death by the creatures.
The movie ends with one of the main cast killing one last demon as the sun rises. The man looks closely at the corpse and sees that it was wearing the same pendant that one of his children was wearing. They then realize that the creatures abducted their kids in order to turn them into demons.
Anyone know what this movie is?
